# Upgrade to kendo UI 2013 Q2 : Combo Box and date picker rending issue in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, kendo-ui

I have just upgraded my application to use kendo UI 2013 Q2 but now  Combo Box and date picker are not rendering properly in Google Chrome. In 2013 Q1 every thing was fine.
Attach screen shot is from kendo Ui demo site. On IE its working fine. Only on Google Chrome UI is messed up. Same issue is there with Date picker.

[image: Example]

Comment: I cannot see any issue in my Chrome, which env do you use (OS and Chrome version). Check this http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/w9PDH/. It might be some additional CSS or some missing CSS

Comment: The screen shot is from Kendo Ui Demo site itself. http://demos.kendoui.com/web/combobox/cascadingcombobox.html